# How do you configure CouchDB vhosts to point to rewrites in design doc

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

Ok so now I've added a rewrites.js file to my Couchapp root folder. In this js file I have...

```
[
   {
       "method": "GET",
       "from": "/home",
       "to": "app/index.html",
   }
]
```

Now when I push the Couchapp, in CouchDB in my _design/rednecks I see it's creating a "rewrites" property with the above js. So this looks all good to me. This is how to do this right?

I changed my local.ini vhost to...

```
[vhosts]
rnr.couchdb:5984 = /rednecks/_design/rednecks
```

In Chrome I enter url...

http://rnr.couchdb:5984/home

I get same error...

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"Document is missing attachment"}
```

That app/index.html attachment is *absolutely* there. I can see it. The app runs fine if I disable rewrites and use the ugly urls. I've tried every variation of the "to" string that I can think of and all I see is that same error above.

Does *anyone* know how to do this?!?!?!....

## Followup...

Ok following Marek's advice and setting my rewrites.json file to this...

```
[
    { "from": "home", "to": "app/index.html" },
    { "from": "lib/*", "to": "app/lib/*" },
    { "from": "js/*", "to": "app/js/*" },
    { "from": "css/*", "to": "app/css/*" },
    { "from": "img/*", "to": "app/img/*" }
]
```

It's almost there. It's starting to come together now thanks to your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you configured your vhost wrong. It should be:

```
[vhosts]
rnr.couchdb:5984 = /rednecks/_design/rednecks/_rewrite
```

Comment: I have the rewrites.json in the Couchapp root. When I push the project to CouchDB, a "rewrites" property is created in the _design/rednecks doc. This property has the content of the rewrites.json file. But your vhosts example above appears to be pointing to some other doc with _id = _design/redecks/_rewrite. What is this other doc for and what is it's content? Couchapp push process doesn't appear to use it, but I could be wrong.

Thanks a lot for your help! I need it :-)